# How to get the contents of the subgroup matched by a regular expression

Tags: regex, shell, grep

like this:
p.txt

```
abc-111-zzz-022-ffff
abc-222-zzz-033-ffff
abc-333-zzz-044-ffff
```

I can get the full match (`$0` in regex):

```sh
[root@ser user]# grep -Po 'abc\-([0-9]+)\-zzz\-([0-9]+)' p.txt
abc-111-zzz-022
abc-222-zzz-033
abc-333-zzz-044
```

How can I get only subgroup content `$1$2` like :

```
111022
222033
333044
```

thanks!

Comment: I am fairly certain you will need to grep twice, once for each capture group using lookahead and lookbehinds (or use something other than grep).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` doesn't allow printing capture groups. Use `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/abc-([0-9]+)-zzz-([0-9]+).*/\1\2/' file

111022
222033
333044
```

Alternatively, if you have `pcregrep` then use this command to print first 2 capture groups:

```sh
pcregrep -o1 -o2 'abc-([0-9]+)-zzz-([0-9]+)' file

111022
222033
333044
```